# In vim, how can I modify all existing indents to be 2?

Tags: vim

In vim, I set shiftwidth=2, but all my previous indents are still at the default 8. How can I change the previous indents from 8 to 2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reindent the whole file with `gg=G`. `gg` goes to the first line, `=` indents (taking a movement), `G` goes to the last line.

Comment: No, tabs are not the same as indents. tabstop vs. shiftwidth.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `set expandtab` (like you *should*), you can modify the indentation in a file with

```
:%s/^ */  /
```

The settings affect how changes are made, but do not themselves make changes to the file.

Answer (score 0):

If your original indents were achieved using hard tabs stops, then one trick you can do is this. Set the hard tab stop to 2:

```
:set ts=2
```

Now you have the two-space indentation (but achieved with hard tabs).

Now, do

```
:retab 8
```

This means, roughly, change the hard tab size to 8 (as if by `:set ts=8`) but at the same time edit all the tabbing in the buffer so that the indentation's appearance does not change.

So now the buffer is still indented to two spaces, but now `:ts` is back to 8.

If you have `:expandtab` set, then the indentation is now all spaces, otherwise it is a combination of 8-space tabs and spaces.

Even if this doesn't apply to your situation, `retab` is good to know because it's handy for dealing with sources that use hard tabs and that you'd like to convert to use spaces  *and* a different indentation level at the same time.